# Mips concatenate two integers, packing them into 16-bit fields in one register

Tags: assembly, mips

I have two integers

```
li $v0, 14
li $v1, 8
```

Since decimal `14` in hex value is `000E` and `8` in hex value is `0008`,
how can I combine `000E` and `0008` to make `000E0008`, so each integer takes up to 16 bits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can shift the first integer left by 16 bits and merge it into the second via bit-wise `OR`:

```
sll $v0, $v0, 16        # $v0 = $v0 << 16
or $v1, $v0, $v1        # $v1 = $v0 | $v1 (result)
```